# How to create a screen saver for Android which will allow to call emergency contact number without unlocking the phone?

Tags: android-studio

I have to create a screen saver for the app I am developing. It should have features like calling emergency contact numbers, dial 911 without unlocking the phone. Is it possible? Any suggestions please.

Comment: Please show your work...

Comment: Hi Sam, that's certainly possible, but we'll need a lot more information. Please show the code you've written so far and what problem specifically that you're having trouble with. Thanks!

Comment: I have not started coding. I am confused if I should be developing it as a widget or a screen saver?